# I need to get a <div> over another one

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building a webapp. The home page "/" has a Carousel-Component and a Navbar-Component on top.

The Navbar-Component has a function `onMouseHover()` that show a div `id="options"` which show up from left to right.

All what I need is when div `id="options"` show up from left to right, I want to see their options instead of the Carousel-Component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
            <Carousel />
        </div>
        </>
    )}
export default Home;
```

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {

    const [isHoveringTrucks, setIsHoveringTrucks] = useState(false)

    return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-around bg-red-600 h-[15%] fixed w-full">
            <div className="group w-16 flex flex-col items-center text-white text-3xl hover:text-opacity-50 cursor-default" onMouseOver={() => setIsHoveringTrucks(true)} onMouseOut={() => setIsHoveringTrucks(false)}>
                <ion-icon name="home-outline">Camiones</ion-icon>
                <div className={`options absolute bg-black top-[108px] left-0 w-full h-[420%] duration-500 ${isHoveringTrucks ? "left-0" : "left-[-100%]"}`}>

                    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-44">
                        <span className="text-lg underline font-bold">Todos</span>
                        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1686534852/Categoria_Multimarcas_xmtzaz.png)` }} className='w-52 h-28 rounded-2xl bg-cover cursor-pointer'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
)}
export default Navbar;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default class Carousel extends Component {

    render() {

        const settings = {dots: true, infinite: true, speed: 500, autoplay: true, 
                            autoplaySpeed: 2000, pauseOnHover: true};

        const images = [
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1679860246/JJ198751U-2_fmfkpo.jpg",
            "https://res.cloudinary.com/depcjbb7q/image/upload/v1679860245/JJ198751U-1_aaiq7x.jpg"
        ]

        return (
                <div className="w-80 h-72">
                    <Slider {...settings}>
                        {images.map((img, index) => (
                            <div key={img}>
                                <img src={img} alt="imagen 1" className="h-56 w-full"></img>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </Slider>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```